# Format Haskell type signatures to be multi-line

Tags: formatting, haskell-mode

I want to have the following functionality on a save hook.

Given a buffer that has type signatures like this…

```
add :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
add x y = x + y
```

…I want to have them reformatted to the following:

```
add
  :: Integer
  -> Integer
  -> Integer
add x y = x + y
```

As far as I can tell `stylish-haskell` does not have this functionality. What are my options?

Comment: What's the use case? That Haskell code is highly idiosyncratic.

Comment: I agree, but I am collaborating with people who prefer multi-line type signatures, and I keep forgetting to format them manually.

Comment: @TianxiangXiong What do you think is so idiosyncratic about it? In my experience multi-line type signatures are not that uncommon; if anything they make complicated type signatures much clearer to read and easier to annotate with, say, haddock. The only thing that stands out to me is the `::` starting on a new line. Here's a module from a popular Haskell project with several such examples: https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Core.hs#L273-L275

Comment: You do it to break up a long line, as you would any piece of code. It's [not the standard](https://github.com/xmonad/xmonad/blob/master/src/XMonad/Core.hs#L243).

Comment: @TianxiangXiong That short lines do not need splitting does not make splitting long lines non-standard or idiosyncratic.