# Emacs lisp refactoring - add variable to surrounding let

Tags: refactoring

## Context

Call me an uncultured non-functional programmer (or call emacs-lisp and uncultured non-functional language), but when I code in *elisp* I tend to use the following pattern (Edit: As an alternative to `let*`)

```
(let (variable1 variable2)
    (setq variable1 (some-function))
    (setq variable2 (some-function))
```

I tend to find this more readable for my uncultured eyes.

Unfortunately, this means there is a lot of jumping back and forward between `let` and `setq`.

## Question

Is there a way for me to quickly and easily insert a name into the surrounding `let` as shown:

```
(let ()
    ...
    CURSOR
```

becomes

```
 (let (variable)
    ...
    CURSOR stays still
```

## Approaches considered

[emr](https://github.com/emacsmirror/emr) has some functions for emacs lisp refactoring. But not the one I want. The closest is extracting variables to let (together with assignment). I had a look at extending this but balked at the amount of code I would need to understand.

I had a brief look at [erefactor](https://github.com/mhayashi1120/Emacs-erefactor), but relevant functionality wasn't there.

**Code it myself** This isn't hard, it's just I would prefer to use someone else's implementation should it exist. This feels like the sort of thing that should exist.

## Edit: An example of why you might want to do this

Here is a function that sums numbers on the two previous lines and inserts the result.

```
(defun sum-lines ()
    (let (a b)
         (previous-line 2)
         (setq a (string-to-int (thing-at-point 'line))
         (forward-line 1)
         (setq b (string-to-int (thing-at-point 'line)))
         (forward-line 1)
         (insert (format "%S" (+ a b))))
```

Do you actaully want to write this as

```
(let* (
   (a (save-excursion (previous-line 2) (thing-at-point 'line))
   (b (save-excursion (previous-line 1) (thing-at-point 'line))
```

or

```
(let* (
   (a (progn (previous-line 2) (thing-at-point 'line))
   (b (progn (next-line 1) (thing-at-point 'line))
```

or

```
(defun line-at (n)
     (save-excursion
        (previous-line n)
      (string-to-int (thing-at-point 'line))

(insert (+ (line-at 2) (line-at 1)))
```

Comment: You write code for people (including yourself in 6 months) to read. When you insist on using your idiosyncratic style, you are making life worse for everyone.

Comment: That's rather a harsh downvote... I would encourage you to temper your behaviour and consider your community. There is a lot to say about coding standard

Comment: ..there is a lot to say about coding standards, readability of code, and the value changes of standards and how they can be achieved by this is not the place to discuss it. If you want to make such comments you should include links to the relevant coding standards considering the audience of this community (a Q&A sites for beginners rather than the emacs mailing list).

Comment: Given that your style is more verbose, less efficient, and not idiosyncratic, I wouldn't make any particular effort to accommodate it.  But maybe you could simply go one step further and just drop the `let` binding ;-)

Comment: @Stefan :P. For some jusfication, this tends to turn up as an alternative to `let*` when you are moving the point around in imperative code, it lets you put the setq's near where you use them. I mean, I wouldn't use this if the `setq` was next to the `let` or I could define the variable at the beginning of the function.

Comment: This reminds me of the question about [multi-line Haskell type signatures](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/32345/format-haskell-type-signatures-to-be-multi-line). My answer: don't do it.

Comment: Please see [Emacs Lisp Coding Conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html) and [Google Common Lisp Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml).

Comment: The emacs coding conventions don't actually mention the `let*` versus `setq`. I guess perhaps I should be reading more common lisp coding guidelines for writing small extensions for my editor. But anyway, yep, a grep of the my *elpa* packages confirms that `let*` is pretty commonly used as an alternative to this (though it is far from universal). Maybe what I really need is a snippet for `(defun $1 () (let* (` combined with `emr-el-extract-to-let` combined with making every function I use take at `point` :/. The whole "coding within let*" effect that you can get feels perverse...

Comment: @sds Also sorry for being a bit grumpy :/.

Comment: I don't understand what "insert a name into the surrounding". Can you please write the "before" and "after" the operation? Writing Lisp code walkers is something every lisper does eventually. It's interesting in and of itself. Also, I'm against of "don't do it" answers in general. There's too much baseless bias in programming community as to how programs should be written on one hand, and on the other hand, a failed experiment could often be a stepping stone to a breakthrough, much more often than a successful iterative one.

Comment: Yes, this question would benefit from a specific before/after example. I think of the `(let (var) ... *assign to var* ...)` approach as very much the exception rather than the rule, but it's not an "avoid at all costs" thing, and there's no reason why a refactoring tool couldn't support it. You may well have to add such support yourself, though.

Comment: Yeah, I missed the word "let" after surrounding. That's fixed. I've also included an example of the refactoring I wanted.

Comment: Interesting and documented question that could be easily enlarged for similar needs, which I use all day long in other languages, like add or remove a function argument without moving the point, with or without refactoring in the module. I encourage you to ask for new features in a github issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my 2 cents :)

```
(defun my-let-add (var)
         (interactive "swhat do add? ")
         (save-excursion
           (beginning-of-defun)
           (search-forward "(let" nil t)
           (search-forward ")" nil t)
           (left-char)
           (unless (looking-back "(")
             (insert " "))
           (insert var)))
```

nice reference: http://wikemacs.org/wiki/Emacs_Lisp_Cheat_Sheet#Positions

Answer (score 1):

Well the profound consensus appears to be **"don`t do that"**, meaning that I'm probably not going to get an answer, and probably shouldn't do that. I guess I'm going to have to answer this myself.

I think the answer for the (probably too broad for SE) *meta-question* of "jumping between `let`'s, `let*'s` and the body of a function is irritating' is a combination of:

- (Obvious but easily forgotten) advice to have small functions, localise side effects, make judicious use recursion and [save-excursion](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/save_002dexcursion.html), making use of [common lisp coding standards](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml) (as suggested by @sds) to make up for the comparative brevity of emacs's [coding guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html).
- When you have side-effect-free code (as [cl coding standards encourage](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml#Mostly_Functional_Style) but is [rarely the case in emacs lisp code](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FunctionalProgramming)) make use of `emr-el-extract-to-let` to avoid jumping around.
- Use `let*` if your variables depend upon one another. This pattern is more common within emacs lisp code than the use of unassigned let expressions (though this is far from universal). `emr-extract-to-let` will place items in a pre-existing `let*`. I'm not sure if `emr-extract-to-let` will order things correctly in `let*` however.
- If you are mutating global state and then using `setq` based upon this state then consider point 1. Alternatively, a common pattern in `emacs lisp` code seems to be using a let-binding with an initial value and ignore it. In which case you could use `emr-extract-to-let` on the value `nil`, possibly with some scripting.
- Put up with it.

I can't help but feeling that functional coding conventions don't necessarily sit well with mutable state (particularly the `(point)` and the various functions that depend upon it).

Comment: The pattern of let-binding variables, then setting them is what `letrec` compiles to. So, assuming you'd actually need to do it that way because of mutually recursive bindings, just use `letrec`. If you don't, well, don't, just use whatever is maximally readable and conveys the meaning best.

Answer (score 1):

My version (avoids inserting into `(let ...)` which is not the dominating node of the variable being promoted):

```
(defun wvxvw/promote-var-to-let (varname)
  (interactive (list (thing-at-point 'symbol)))
  (save-excursion
    (while (not (looking-at "(let"))
      (backward-up-list))
    (when (looking-at "(let")
      (forward-word)
      (forward-sexp)
      (backward-char)
      (insert "\n" varname)
      (forward-char)
      (backward-sexp)
      (indent-sexp))))
```

Note that introducing `let` automatically, when none found is a non-trivial task. It isn't possible to know if you are crossing the boundary of where `let` can be inserted (eg. if you step over `defun`). This is so because if you have a macro that expands to `lambda`, you cannot insert `let` outside of it, but trying to figure out if particular lisp form will expand to `lambda` isn't generally possible.